# Change request payload in Nuxt Auth

Tags: oauth-2.0, nuxt.js

I have this Facebook strategy:

```
facebook: {
  access_token_endpoint: 'http://***.**/api/v0/auth/social',
  access_type: 'offline',
  client_id: '*******',
  grant_type: 'authorization_code',
  redirect_uri: socialLoginUrl + '/account/aanmelden',
  response_type: 'code',
  token_key: 'jwt',
  userinfo_endpoint: 'https://****.***.**/user/profile'
},
```

When I try to register with Facebook I get the following form in the request:

```
code: **
client_id: **
redirect_uri: **
response_type: **
grant_type: **
```

I want to supply some data to the back-end when I register:

```
"attributes":{
  "code":"*****",
  "vendor":"Facebook"
},
```

How do I add this to the form that's being sent to the `access_token_endpoint` ?

// updated question.

Calling the loginWith function:

```
@click="$auth.loginWith('facebook', { params: data })"
```

data object:

```
data () {
  return {
    data: {
      type: 'user',
      attributes: {
        vendor: 'Facebook',
        code: '**'
      }
    },
  }
},
```

Request payload in the browser:

`code=**&client_id=**&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Faccount%2Faanmelden&response_type=code&grant_type=authorization_code`

Response from the back-end:

[image]

I expect the `data` object to be available in the payload, but I'm not sure if I'm doing this correctly.

Answer (score 0):

From the official docs, it looks like you can do

```js
this.$auth.loginWith('facebook', { params: { /* additional authentication parameters */ } })
  .then(() => this.$toast.success('Logged In!'))
```

I never used it with Facebook but it's working great with `local` (using JWT).

The related part of the documentation: https://auth.nuxtjs.org/api/auth#loginwithstrategyname-args

Comment: Doesn't seem to work, unless I'm misunderstanding it. I've added the data to the params object, but the request payload isn't changing.

Comment: Do we agree that you call this method (`this.$auth.loginWith`) somewhere in your code ?

Comment: Updated the question to better reflect the current situation.

Comment: Do you actually send the payload properly, double check in the network "headers" little tab. Also, are you sure the params that you're passing are in the good format ?

Comment: The issue is that the request payload is incorrect.

Comment: I mean: "that it should look like that". Ofc it's not passing the good values here, but are those the values awaited by the backend ? Double check if what you're sending is not discarded by the backend and it basically strips all the incorrect params.